# Passing non-Global C++ objects to Lua functions (Swig)

Tags: c++, lua, swig

I am extending an interface with lua, and I've run into a problem in that I would need to pass pointers to objects to the lua code to work upon. These classes will have been wrapped via SWIG, and I could instantiate them via lua using swig, but that would leave me with useless objects.

I need to be able to pass a callback object to lua, as well as objects representing things on events. I cannot manually define the callback as global because that would introduce a constraint which is unnacceptable.

So for a generic example, given a class C and a function in lua that takes 1 parameter, how do I call that lua function while passing it the C++ pointer of type C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aha, answering my own question, but I founds it!

http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2007-05/msg00053.html

> Hello Joey,
>
> I do almost all my SWIG-LUA work from
>   the lua side. Swig is really good for
>   just wrappering up a C/C++ library to
>   get it readable by lua. Getting the
>   C++ to talk to lua is fairly easy, but
>   not well documented.
>
> You idea of `lua_pushlightuserdata(`),
>   was close, but not there. You probably
>   want something like this:
>
> ```
> Foo* p= new Foo();
> SWIG_NewPointerObj(L,p,SWIGTYPE_p_Foo,1);
> lua_setglobal (L, "p");
> ```
>
> The SWIG_NewPointerObj() creates a
>   userdata (not a lightuserdata) for the
>   foo object & pushes it to the stack.
>   The last param (in this case 1) is
>   whether you want lua to manage the
>   memory (0 for no, 1 for yes).
>
> The `SWIG_NewPointerObj()` and
>   `SWIGTYPE_p_Foo` are both found in the
>   wrapping file.
>
> Once you have that you should be able
>   to do in lua:
>
> ```
> print(p)
> print(swig_type(p))
> p:some_function()
> ```
>
> Let me know if you have any other
>   questions. Regards, Mark

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Swig with C++ and Lua, but you can do it without Swig in two different ways (userdata and closures). I don't know if Swig interferes somehow with this.

[Using Userdata](http://www.lua.org/pil/28.html)

[lua_pushcclosure](http://www.lua.org/pil/27.3.3.html)